# Visualize onkeypress line breaks in textarea with REACT

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

what is a valid approach to visualize a text created inside a textarea element with the correctly assigned line breaks?

As soon as I input a line break by pressing Enter key, I can see that this is displayed inside the textarea correctly but when I visualize the output in another element, the line break appears as a space. The data is also saved in my database without any line breaks.

I have attached a sample code to the link below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hodgkin-1oujz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be through CSS, by following:

```
...
<div className="App">
  <div className="wrapper">
    <div>
      <p class='formatted'>{text}</p>
    </div>
...
```

And then: `.formatted { white-space: pre; }`

Another way would be using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
...
<div className="wrapper">
  <div>
    <p
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: formattedText,
      }}>
    </p>
  </div>
...
```

And the logic to handle that would be:

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const [formattedText, setFormattedText] = useState(text);

const handleTextInput = ({ target }) => {
  const { value } = target;
  const formattedValue = value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');

  setText(value);
  setFormattedText(formattedValue);
};
```

Comment: thank you. white-space: pre; works great for me!

Answer (score 0):

There's some possible approachs to your problem. In few words, `\n` new line characters on textarea does not work on plain html. Instead, we could use `<br />`.

Instead of simply rendering text as it's stored, you could split into new lines and render `<br />` in its place:

```
      <p>
        {text.split('\n').map((subtext) => (
          <>
            {subtext}
            <br/>
          </>
        ))}
      </p>
```